# Blazor Copy BASE64 Image from Variable to Clipboard

Tags: image, file, base64, blazor, clipboard

Please tell me :

1. how can I copy a BASE64 image stored into a variable from variable to clipboard ?
2. how can I save a BASE64 image stored into a variable from variable to a file on disk ?

Is there a free Nuget package for this kind of task ?

I am using Blazor, C# and .NET 6.

Thank You Very Much !

Comment: StackOverflow isn't your typical question and answer site. You are unlikely to get someone to write a bunch of code to solve your problem. Try boiling down your question to something specific and show us the code you have written and explain where it's not working. You may want to review [ask].

Comment: I have a BASE64 image stored into a variable like :
VAR_IMAGE_STRING="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAAApgAAAKYB3X3/OAAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZ5vuPBoAAANCSURBVEiJtZZPbBtFFMZ/M7ubXdtdb1xSFyeilBapySVU8h8OoFaooFSqiihIVIpQBKci6KEg9Q6H9kovIHoCIVQJJCKE1ENFjnAgcaSGC6rEnxBwA04Tx43t2FnvDAfjkNibxgHxnWb2e/u992bee7tCa0" *Because of the number of the allowed characters limitations, the image is not complete.*


Please tell me :

how can I copy variable to clipboard ?

how can I save variable to a file on disk ?

Comment: Can you tell me why you deleted the reply of an user and my reply posted a few hours ago ?!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. I don't have permissions to delete anything from this site except my own posts/comments.

Comment: I was not referring to you, Lex but i posted one reply for you and it was deleted !
As you can see your reply to me was deleted too !

Comment: For the first question :
I used the CurrieTechnologies.Razor.Clipboard provided by you but the function copies only the TEXT stored into clipboard, not the IMAGE. I need the IMAGE to be copied so I can paste it as IMAGE into graphics software like PAINT or CORELDRAW !
base64String="iVBORw0KGgoA"....;
await clipboard.WriteTextAsync(base64String);
Thank You !

Comment: For the second question :
I couldn't make it work at all !
var base64String="iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN"....
var decoded_img_tmp = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\1\\newfile.png", convert.FromBase64String(base64String));

I get no error but also no result !
I am developing a Blazor Webassembly App and I use Visual Studio 2022, C#, .NET 6.